# Netbeans - Black JPane when mouse passes by

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm working in a project with the build tool of graphic interface of Netbeans and, when I move the cursor through a JFrame or a JOptionPane (I just use these ones), it becomes black, without show any components like buttons or text fields. But if I pass the mouse on a componente, it appears, like that:

[image: Black JPane Illustrated]

So, someone has a solution for this problem?

(I'm sorry about the English... I'm a brazillian that is in the third level (of six) of his English course)

Comment: It looks to me like a bug in the program, most likely in your code. I don't think anyone can help without seeing the offending code.

Comment: It's strange, because the only thing that I changed was the name of the LookAndFeel, as I did in another projects... But I will keep searching for bugs in my code, thanks.

Comment: I've seen this when using a ATI based video card. It has something to do with the directs driver (off the top of head). There are some settings you can try, it you'll need to google for them

Comment: **[This](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/55813-issue-black-painting-swing-form.html)** post may help.